# Better way to show the calendars

Tags: controls, dates, filter, website-design

I'm working on a single report page for a web app. I need to show how to filter the displayed data it be per day (diary) or between two dates (weekly).

When the user select diary (Diario), it shows a calendar like this:

[image]

If the user wants a weekly (Semanal) report, it shows a second calendar like this:

[image]

[image]
[image]

My question is: Is there a better way to show both calendars to the user, I mean, to get a better interaction with less clicks?, in that case what is the downside of the actual design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my oppinion the optimal workflow would be to let the user choose a timespan he wants the report for and then either via dropdown or radiobuttons choose wheather they are monthly, weekly or daily. Date fields should be filled out with the current date per default.

As for the two other radiobuttons I do not know your databasis but "inspection conducted" and "kg harvested" look a lot like informations that come out of a database and should be in the report and not in the form where the report is generated. Unless, ofcourse you are saving individual reports and just want to indicate that these two things have been done.

Anyway, my form suggestion:
[image: Mockup]

Comment: This is similar to what bing travel does http://www.bing.com/travel/ or pretty much any other travel site, where if you select one-way or round trip it will hide or show the extra calendar selection.

Comment: I use those options (radio buttons) to generate the report from the saved data on the database, when the user select one of the two options the report is generated.

Comment: Then this should be more obvious to the user for example a real button.